# Maven 3 using more memory to build than Maven 2

Tags: maven, maven-2, heap-memory, maven-3

I'm using Maven 3.1.1 to build a large project and it will run out of Java Heap Space every build. I cannot further increase the heap space due to Windows 32-bit limitations. However, the same project will build fine with Maven 2.2.1.

There are a few modules within the project that build with using more memory with Maven 3 compared to Maven 2. However when breaking down those module to each individual submodule and building them, each submodule does not use more memory with Maven 3 on its own.

I was wondering what is different about Maven 3 compared to Maven 2 that might cause this to happen?

Comment: I have no definitive answer for you, but the dependency resolution in 3 is entirely revamped, being more accurate and at the same time more thorough. A problem that we had at that time was the use of dependency ranges, which lead to all the paths being explored, taking a lot of time (and I believe memory).

Comment: Just to be sure: Didn't you limited the maximum memory usage on Maven 2? In my case, Maven3 was lighter then v2 using the default configuration.

Anyway, I always set the min and max memory for Maven, and always put both with the same value, avoind changes in memory allocation.